# Magento 2.3.5: Remove category page bottom toolbar title and filters and keep only pagination

Tags: magento2, php, category, toolbar, pager

I want to remove the title, filter and sort from the bottom toolbar on the category page and leave only the pager (pagination).

My toolbar phtml is located at

**vendor/vendor_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>

<?php
$list_count = $this->helper('Ecomwares\Wokiee\Helper\Data')->getSystemValue('wokiee_settings/product_listing/list_count');
?>

<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="toolbar toolbar-products" data-mage-init='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getWidgetOptionsJson() ?>'>
        <div class="tt-filters-options">
            <?php if ($this->helper('Ecomwares\Wokiee\Helper\Data')->checkPage() == 'catalog_category_view'): ?>
            <h1 class="tt-title">
                <?= $block->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->getPageTitle(); ?>
                <?php if ($list_count): ?>
                    <span class="tt-title-total">(<?= $block->getTotalNum(); ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </h1>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('category.description'); ?>
            <div class="tt-btn-toggle">
                <a href="#"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Filter') ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="tt-sort">
                <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
                    <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/sorter_custom.phtml')) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/limiter_custom.phtml')) ?>
            </div>
            <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
                <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/viewmode_custom.phtml')) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
    </div>

<?php endif ?>
```

and the category list.phtml file is located at

**vendor/vendor_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml**

and the toolbar.phtml gets called for the top toolbar as such

```
<div class="top-toolbar">
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

and for the bottom toolbar as such

```
<div class="bottom-toolbar">
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

I want just the pager to show on the botttom toolbar so I changed it to

```
<div class="bottom-toolbar">
    <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
</div>
```

However it doesn't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on mobile and i resolve it with CSS.

```
#mana_ajax_wrapper_category_products_list .toolbar-products:last-of-type, #mana_ajax_wrapper_search_result .toolbar-products:last-of-type{
    .open-filters{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already done that, the thing is it loads view page source, and as a result shows 2 <h1> tags on the page. Which is why I want to remove it from the page.